# build javascript array from another function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a translation function I call like this : _("My text").

I am trying to build an array :

```
    var data = {
                        _("region"):[
                            {"id": "vignoble","name": _("Vineyard") },
                            {"id": "sousvignoble","name": _("Sub Vineyard") },
                            {"id": "soussousvignoble","name": _("Sub Sub Vineyard") },
                            {"id": "appellation","name": _("Appellation") },
                            {"id": "denomination","name": _("Denomination") }
                        ]};
```

It works great for translating property "name" : _("My text") but throws a "Syntax Error : Missing : after property id" for first level _("region").

I've tried to replace it by :
1. function(){_("region")}
2. define a variable and replace _("region") by the variable but the name of variable prints and not its value

Any idea would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic property names in object literals. You can assign the property after the object was created, using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation):

```
var data = {};
data[_("region")] = [...];
```